# AngularJS Arrays - objects with data present in multiple tables

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to make an application as a side project for myself to get used to angularjs, which I don't have much experience with, and I'm trying to come up with a method of using different data for different teams in a table without making various controllers, as I'm making different tables where each team will be present but their associated data attributes are different each time.

So rather than making multiple controller like this for each year (here for 2010)...

```
app.controller('2010controller', function() {

    var teams = [ 
        {
            name: 'Team One',
            position: 1,
            played: 38,
            won: 27,
            drawn: 5,
            lost: 6,
            goalsFor: 103,
            goalsAgainst: 32,
            goalDifference: 71,
            points: 86
        },
        {
            name: 'Team Two',
            position: 2,
            played: 38,
            won: 27,
            drawn: 4,
            lost: 7,
            goalsFor: 86,
            goalsAgainst: 28,
            goalDifference: 58,
            points: 85
        },
    ]

});

})
```

...is there any way of giving giving the same teams different data without creating various controllers?

Comment: Do you have HTML template that goes with this controller? The one where this controller is loaded?

Comment: Why in the world you would need different controller for different year. Why not keep all in one list/array/table. Am i missing something?

Comment: mbeso - Because otherwise each team would need a 2010 position attribute, 2011, 2012, 2013 etc.... As well as for all of their other attributes

Comment: use a service to get data, given year as a parameter to the service. Every controller can inject this service and load required year, and work in a generic way